# anchor tag design changes in mobile safari

Tags: css

so am designing this website and my anchor tags looks fine in desktop and android mobiles but in safari it changes to a pill type button. i mean thhe (how it works and pricing buttons)

[image]

but originally it should look like this

[image]

this is the code of those two buttons

```
<a href="/" type="button" class="btn text-white active p-2 pt-4 pb-4 " style="font-family:roboto;font-size: 18px;">
text.How it works
</a>
<a href="/" type="button" class="btn text-center text-white p-2 pt-4 pb-4 " style="font-family:roboto; font-size: 18px;">
          Pricing
                </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing type="button" from anchor tag.